# Произвести множественную выборку в MySQL (вложенный SELECT)

Tags: mysql, select, биоинформатика

Есть две таблицы:

Таблица мутаций

```
 CREATE TABLE `mut_pat_012345_01012017` (
  `chromosome` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `possibility` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `chr_pos` (`chromosome`,`position`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

И стандартная дополненная таблица, описывающая координаты и свойства генов:

```
CREATE TABLE `genes-g38-201505` (
  `chromosome` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `left` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `right` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Complement` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `source` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `ENSEMBL` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `gene_version` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `gene_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `gene_source` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `gene_biotypeid` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  <...> ещё куча полей, не имеющих значения
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=60434 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 
  COMMENT='Таблица генов для генома версии p38 май 2015';
```

Я всегда могу сделать вложенный запрос на получение всех мутаций пациента, входящих в определенный ген, таким образом:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `mut_pat_012345_01012017` 
where `position` > ( SELECT `left` FROM `genes-g38-201505` where `id` =1 )
  and `position` < (SELECT `right` FROM `genes-g38-201505` where `id` =1) ;
```

Но при попытке сделать это одновременно для двух генов, желая получить все записи вместе (т.е. записи для гена с id=2 и для гена с id=3, фактически, сложить множества) вот так:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `mut_pat_012345_01012017` 
where `position` > ( SELECT `left` 
                     FROM `genes-g38-201505` 
                     where `id` > 1 and `id` < 4 ) 
  and `position` < ( SELECT `right` 
                     FROM `genes-g38-201505` 
                     where `id` > 1 and `id` < 4 ) ;
```

система ругается, что не может обработать множественный запрос.

Два вопроса:

1. Как правильно выполнить такой запрос? Через Union? А если я хочу получить данные не по двум генам, а по нескольким? То есть взять сложить все множества записей для генов, например, с id от 1 до 20.
2. Можно ли будет в таком  полученном ответе как-то делить данные, принадлежащие разным генам? Не хочется делать несколько запросов, это очень долго.

Comment: *система ругается, что не может обработать множественный запрос* Правильно ругается. В первом запросе Вы сравниваете число с числом, нормально. А во втором хотите сравнивать число с пачкой чисел, что не имеет смысла. Вам следует избавиться от подзапросов, переписав всё на JOIN.

Comment: Если формализовать задачу, то получится нечто такое: имеется набор отрезков (это гены), задан отрезок (мутация), надо определить пересечения (полное вхождение, частичное вхождение, касание, отсутствие общих точек). В таком виде задача вполне стандартна. Если не сказать, что обсосана со всех сторон...

Comment: @Akina А мне кажется (у нас бывают похожие задачи), что ТС нужно не пересечение, а все вхождения, просто сразу для нескольких генов. Но, конечно, пусть расскажет сам ТС

Comment: @ViktorTomilov *ТС нужно не пересечение, а все вхождения, просто сразу для нескольких генов* Это следующий шаг - и его решение показано в ответе **Mike**.

Comment: Мне действительно нужны все вхождения, т.е. получить, в данном случае, и результаты для гена id=2 и для гена id=3, все вместе. Видимо, я некорректно задал вопрос, попробую переформулировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать что то в этом роде:

```
SELECT P.*
  FROM `mut_pat_012345_01012017` P, genes-g38-201505 G
 where G.id >1 and G.id < 4
   and P.`position` > G.left and P.`position` < G.right
 group by P.`chromosome`, P.`position`
having count(1)=2 /* 2 - количество подходящих генов */
```

Последние условие (having) необходимо, если вы хотите получить только такие записи из первой таблицы, для которых есть пересечения из обоих (или более) ID второй таблицы, одноврмененно. Если вам надо найти записи, для которых есть пересечение хотя бы с одной записью во второй таблице, `having count(1)=2` надо убрать.

Comment: @Akina Ну 4х :) Не придирайтесь, конечно имелось ввиду странное условие указанное у ТС

Comment: Нет, увы, ваш запрос даёт именно пересечение, т.е. только общие записи для генов с id = 2 и id=3 (так я могу сделать с помощью UNION), а мне нужно сложение, т.е .все записи вместе

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov А про сложение я написал в комментарии, просто уберите `having count(1)=2` и будет вам сложение. А если при этом надо что бы в случае сложения записи появлялись столько раз, сколько было совпадений, уберите `group by` (ну и можете в этом случае в выборку добавить поля из genes, что бы было ясно что именно совпало)

Comment: Всё, разобрался, спасибо!